# Dynamically Access Properties by Type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to access a property that is the same type of which is passed into a generic.

Look at the code:

```
class CustomClass
{
    CustomProperty property {get; set;}
}

class CustomProperty
{
}

Main
{
        // Create a new instance of my custom class
        CustomClass myClass = new CustomClass();

        // Create a new instance of another class that is the same type as myClass.property
        CustomProperty myProp = new CustomProperty();

        // Call the generic method 
        DynamicallyAccessPropertyOnObject<CustomProperty>(myProp, myClass);
}


private void DynamicallyAccessPropertyOnObject<T>(this T propertyToAccess, CustomClass class)
{
    // I want to access the property (In class) that is the same type of that which is passed in the generic (typeof(propertyToAccess))

    // TODO: I need help accessing the correct property based on the type passed in
}
```

If you can't see from the code. Basically I want to be able to pass in a something into a generic and then access the property on a class that is of the same type as the thing that was passed in.

Is there a good way to do this?
If you need clarification let me know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Reflection, and `LINQ`:

```
private static void DynamicallyAccessPropertyOnObject<T>()
{
    var customClass = typeof(CustomClass);
    var property = customClass
                  .GetProperties()
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(T));

}
```

If you are doing this for `CustomClass` only, you can remove both parameters.Then you can call it:

```
DynamicallyAccessPropertyOnObject<CustomProperty>();
```

If you want to generalize it, use two generic arguments:

```
private static void DynamicallyAccessPropertyOnObject<T, K>(K targetObj)
{
    var targetType = targetObj.GetType();

    var property = targetType
                  .GetProperties()
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(T));

    if(property != null) 
    {
       var value = (T)property.GetValue(targetObj);
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
DynamicallyAccessPropertyOnObject<CustomProperty,CustomClass>(myClass);
```

Comment: You actually don't need the first argument, since you are just using the type information which is already present in the generic argument.

Comment: Very useful, especially with the two generics.

Comment: @ShalinVed you are right thanks. I have updated the code and removed the redundant parameters

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one such property you can do:

```
var prop = typeof(CustomClass).GetProperties().First(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T));
object value  = prop.GetValue(@class, null);
```

you can set the value with `SetValue`:

```
object valueToSet = ...
prop.SetValue(@class, valueToSet);
```

Comment: Ok cool. That grabs the property. Now if you look at my method in combination with your code. Is there a way to drill down into class passed in and access that property on the class passed in. It would look like `class.prop`

Comment: @OhaxNuv - I'm not sure what you mean - the second line gets the value of the property on the instance you pass in.

Comment: I guess I was wondering if it was possible to `set` the value of the property as well.

Comment: @OhaxNuv - You can set the value with `SetValue` - see update.